# RandomizedSearchCV most optimal combination

Tags: python

Is there a way to see which combination of settings has resulted in an optimal result when you use `RandomizedSearchCV`?

Comment: I'm not going to try to pretend to understand any of SKLearn, but it would seem you can dump parameters based on [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_randomized_search.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-randomized-search-py) example. Hopefully that helps.